# How to install Samba on macOS

Tags: macos, samba

I want to install a Samba server on my Mac.

I tried this article [Compiling SAMBA 4 file-sharing server on Mac OS-X High Sierra](https://medium.com/@mattmatic/compiling-samba-4-on-mac-os-x-high-sierra-24ca6a93a51c) but got an error on the configure step:

```
./configure \ 
       --prefix=/opt/samba \
       --without-ad-dc \
       --without-acl-support
```

**Error message**

```
Error: /Users/user/samba/source4/lib/tls/wscript:51:
error: Building the AD DC requires GnuTLS (eg libgnutls-dev, gnutls-devel) for ldaps:// support and for the BackupKey protocol
```

Is there a way to install a Samba server on macOS?

P.S. Another decision of my task is to create "public file share" on macOS like in this article - https://websiteforstudents.com/create-public-samba-share-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/. But I can't find where located buld-in file sharing configuration file.

Comment: Did you see the comment from Thomas Johnson in the article linked from yours: [Compiling and Running Samba 4 Server on macOS](https://willhaley.com/blog/compile-samba-macos/)?  *"I had to install Homebrew to handle a few dependencies:
**brew install pkg-config gnutls**
./configure --prefix=/opt/samba --without-acl-support --enable-debug
make*" (my emphasis)

Comment: @ lx07, yes I have tried this, it help me did "configure". I've got another error when I trying to execute "sudo make". And I no idea what I should do with this.

Comment: Doesn't macOS include an SMB server?  It's probably version 2 or 3, but if you just need to share files, there is a built-in Sharing option.

Comment: @jimtut It does, but it's severely restricted due to iOS style file management that prevents you from anything Apple didn't plan for... like proxying an FTP/S3 or Box.com share over Samba